# Dual monitor flickers and resets periodically

Tags: nvidia, dell, intel-graphics, thinkpad, external-monitor

I have a Lenovo thinkpad T530 with Ubuntu 12.10 installed. When I connect an external monitor (Acer 23') to my laptop it works fine, but both screens flicker periodically and gets reset. The applications opened in the external monitor moves to the laptop screen when reset. Is this a problem with the graphics card driver? Is there a solution for this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Does this also occur on Windows? Ever tried changing screen/cable?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your BIOS.  There is a BIOS update for some of these models that include:
Fixed an issue that might have screen corruption on Linux.

http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles/g4uj14uc.txt